# How D4 is calculated (Range Charts)

Tags: statistics

The formulas for the chart are found below:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185373/closed-formula-for-d4-constant-calculation-moving-range-chart-constant

My question is what the x1, xn represent in these formula's (see formula a1 and an).

Comment: Can you put the question here instead of in a link? Links may die, which would make your question nonsensical.

Comment: Why not ask this question on that site?

Comment: I will @YiFan Also, i have understood that it's a "temporary variable". I'm trying to convert it to code, though and i don't see how to translate a temporary variable to code. Can i assign it a value